# Broadcom NIC support on FreeBSD 8.3

Tags: freebsd, networkcard, broadcom

I'd like to know if the following network cards are supported:

```
    Broadcom netxtreme II 1000 express dual port ethernet adapter
    Broadcom netxtreme II 1000 express quad port ethernet adapter
```

I've seen that chipset is BCM5709C, I wonder if it's the same that "Broadcom NetXtreme II BCM5709 1000Base-T" mentioned at https://www.freebsd.org/releases/8.3R/hardware.html#ETHERNET

It must be such a version, newer versions I cannot use it.

Comment: Looks Supported to Me.  [Right from the Developer's Mouth](http://forum.broadcom.com/showthread.php?2452-BCM5709-support-on-FreeBSD)

Answer (score -1):

It is a crap shoot as Broadcom is changing chip sets even for the same card types. My I ask you why do you even bother with Broadcom when 1Gigabit dual Intel controller goes for $10 on e-bay?

Comment: It's not an answer at all. It could be better as a I-Want-To-Scream-Something comment.